# MySQL - saving date and time as DATETIME vs as saving date and time as String

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I need to store a deadline, that consists of a date and a time (e.g 2016-05-02 19:02). I am currently using a field that has DATETIME as datatype but the problem is that its automatically saving it as 2016-05-02 19:02:00.

as a solution i was thinking to save the date in a String field.

So i am wondering if i should do that ? any performance advantages/disadvantages ?

Comment: Instead of saving the date as a String, you should be able to get the date only without the time in your SQL query. You should show what your SQL query looks like.

Comment: i need to save both , time and date. the problems is , that its added seconds when storing

Comment: What's wrong with the seconds being stored? That's what a date is. You'll waste time  saving dates as strings, especially when retrieving. And you lose the ability to use operators like `BETWEEN`.

Comment: just disliking the idea that unwanted seconds are being stored. so i started to wonder if it was better to save it as string. but reading your arguments, it does not seem like that , so i guess i will stick with DATETIME.

Answer (score 2):

Don't fight the database. Use the builtin types unless you *really* need something that they can't offer(I'd say it's unlikely, though). (And by this I mean that you should use TIME, DATE or similar for times and dates. Then you can do calculations without having to convert values, etc)

If you don't need the seconds then just keep them 00 all the time.

Whether you use DATETIME, DATE & TIME or perhaps TIMESTAMP is up to you, how you use the data. Choose the alternative that makes most sense in your current situation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, you should always use built-in data types whenever possible.

In your case, stick with `DATETIME` and then convert it to whatever format you need in the query using the `DATE_FORMAT` function, like so:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `mytable`;
+----+---------------------+
| id | mydatetime          |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2016-06-06 14:12:00 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`mydatetime`,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') AS `mydatetime` FROM `mytable`;
+----------------------+
| mydatetime           |
+----------------------+
| Jun 06 2016 02:12 PM |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp